# Bash problem Mac OS Terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, bash, command-line

Hi when I pressed the up arrow to see the previous command, it rewrote the current command from half.

Example:

```
21 /usr/local/sphinx/etc >  /usr/local/sphinx/bin/search --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx-blog.conf php
```

and when I press the up arrow, it shows:

```
21 /usr/local/sphinx/etc >  /usr/local/sudo /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx-blog.conf --all
```

and "/usr/local/" before SUDO is from previous command. Do you know where the problem would be? Here is my prompt setting:

```
PS1="\# \e[32;1m\w > \e[0m "
```

Comment: and when i use BACKSPACE i will delete up to 21 /usr/local/sphinx/etc >  /usr/local/       i'm not able to delete /usr/local/

Comment: Could you pleas execute `read` on the command line and then press the up-arrow? (you can exit `read` with ctrl+c) In theory, this should give `^[[A` or `\e[A` (reps. `^[[B` or `\e[B` for the down-arrow). Did you maybe configure bind for your arrow keys (eg. in the ~/.bash_profile)?

Comment: I tried it `18 ~ >  /usr/local/read
^[[A^[[B^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[B^[[B`

Comment: All of those characters appeared when you pressed the up arrow just once??  If so, then @Asmus is correct and something is wrong with your configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I tried around and finally managed to find the error: you need to use even more escape sequences in your PS1 - this should work:

```
export PS1="\# \[\e[32;1m\]\w > \[\e[0m\]"
```

note the additional `\[` and `\]` that wrap the colour escape sequences.